# How to upload files from file manager without using iCloud?

Tags: react-native, picker

I want to upload doc and pdf files from my React Native app. I used React Native document picker but it works with iCloud and I want to select files from the file manager.

Here is my code:

```
import { DocumentPicker, DocumentPickerUtil } from 'react-native-document-picker';

selectFile(type,index='') {
      DocumentPicker.show({
       filetype: [DocumentPickerUtil.allFiles()],
         },(error,res) => {

           console.log(
              res.uri,
              res.type, // mime type
              res.fileName,
              res.fileSize
           );
         });
}
```